IISExpress and IIS stopped working after netsh iplisten
My IIS was only listening on localhost and not IP so I ran following command:
netsh http add iplisten 10.0.0.10
After this IISExpress and IIS both have stopped working. I cannot access websites using localhost, or 127.0.0.1 or 10.0.0.10. What happened?

IIS Express is designed for application development. It isn't intended to host applications, or function on a host with IIS at the same time. For details on how to use IIS Express in a development environment in this way, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866547/binding-iis-express-to-an-ip-address
